# How properly bundle scss/sass files with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, sass, styles, bundle, angular-cli

Trying to migrate from gulp to angular-cli. In gulp we have a separate plugin for scss bundling -- just run the task and a result to index.html...

Comment: what version of the cli are you on?

Answer (score 3):

When installing a project using angular-cli, it makes use of `css` by default. In order to use scss you need to do the following:

- install node-sass using `npm install node-sass --save-dev` (this is used to compile scss to css)
- rename css files to `.scss`
- update all references to `css` files to use the correct url

That's all you should be required to do in order to use scss.

See: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i8k7578pr1klsl/angular-cli-test.zip?dl=0 for a running example

Note: all scss that does not belong to components should go into `styles.scss` (which was previously names `styles.css`, but you've just renamed it).